# Google Firebase Config APIs

Tags: python, firebase, rest, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to call PUT apis of google firebase but I am getting code: 400 error.

```py
payload = {
  "parameters": [{
    "key": "key1",
    "defaultValue": [{
      "value": "123"
    }]
    }, {
    "key": "otherKey",
    "defaultValue": [{
      "value": "456"
    }]
  }]
}

response = authed_session.put(
  "https://firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/v1/projects/test/remoteConfig",
  data = payload
)
```

[image]
I have modified payload with different combination but it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that the payload you’re sending may not be valid. Looking at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/remote-config/rest/v1/projects/updateRemoteConfig), the expected request body is an instance of [RemoteConfig](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/remote-config/rest/v1/RemoteConfig). So the `payload` would look like:

```
payload = {
    "parameters": {
        "key1": {
          "defaultValue": {
            "value": "123"
          },
          "valueType": "STRING"
        },
        "key2": {
          "defaultValue": {
            "value": "456"
          },
          "valueType": "STRING"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, convert your `payload` into a JSON-formatted string then pass it to the `data` argument  of `authed_session.put`. Note that I’m passing `If-Match: *` in the `headers` which forces an update:

```
response = authed_session.put(
  "https://firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/remoteConfig",
  data=json.dumps(payload),
  headers={
    "If-Match": "*"
  }
)
```

Alternatively, you can just pass the payload into the `json` argument  of `authed_session.put`:

```
response = authed_session.put(
  "https://firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/remoteConfig",
  json=payload,
  headers={
    "If-Match": "*"
  }
)
```

Complete code would look like:

```
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
  <SERVICE_ACCOUNT_OBJECT>,
  scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.remoteconfig',
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)

authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials=credentials)

payload = {
    "parameters": {
        "key1": {
          "defaultValue": {
            "value": "123"
          },
          "valueType": "STRING"
        },
        "key2": {
          "defaultValue": {
            "value": "456"
          },
          "valueType": "STRING"
        }
    }
}

response = authed_session.put(
  "https://firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/remoteConfig",
  json=payload,
  headers={
    "If-Match": "*"
  }
)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this and it resolved my issue. 
is there any other way to do because when I am hitting this. it is removing the current config and adding current json